# Showing two users with same account name in same domain and same computer

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I am new to active-directory.

my server domain name is 'VIANOVA', and there is a user 'edith'. I think I have made some changes in 'last name' of user account properties in Active-directory, now i am getting a fresh desktop when i have logged in and old desktop and files are missing..

When i have checked windows users in same computer it is showing one user as 'edith' and one user as 'edith.VIANOVA'. (See the image)

Why it is showing like this ? How can I take my old desktop ? unfortunately I forgot what are the changes I have made in account properties.

Please help to solve the issue

Comment: Try copying the users profile over to a folder called Edith.backup and delete both the Edith and the Edith.VIANOVA folder from the users folder.  Next have that user login to her new desktop and create a new folder on the desktop.  Have the user logout and log back in and see if the folder she created on her desktop is still there or if it is gone.  If it is still there, copy items from the backup folder back to the new Edith folder in the users folder.  If that does not work, these sorts of issues are common and sometimes very tricky to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Use ForensIT user profile wizard to move data from one profile to the other. It's a free tool designed for this job.